# Insert two variable inside one argument of a function

Tags: c

I have a question, can I declare two variables in an argument of a function? For ex, `void Led_On(uint8 port, uint8 pin)`. I want turn on LED in pin 0 and pin 1 but I don't want to call another function. Is there any way to call two variable in one argument? For example I have a blue LED and red LED in Pin 0 and Pin 1, can I declare blue LED and red LED inside the the `uint8 pin` argument?? Is there any way??

Comment: Make the question more elaborated. Like specify what you want finally by an example and what problem are facing currently?

Comment: I will edit a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cant call a 2-argument function with just one argument, but a wrapper function around that One would be trivial

Answer (score 0):

Its thoroughly depends on your implementation of `Led_On` function.  Say, you don't want to add a new argument then you can just treat the argument `uint8 pin` 
itself to identify 8 different pins using bit maps. Or another way is you can modify the type of `uint8 pin`  to an array to specify all the pins to be turned ON.

And if the `Led_On` function is abstracted to you and you can't modify it, then you probably have to run it twice for turning ON two LEDs because even if you get a way of specifying two variables in an argument, then also `Led_On` is implemented in such a way that it only handles a pin at a time

Comment: Thanks for your comment =D. I will try it.